# How to Implementing wired 802.1x in Win2k3 R2 and Windows XP SP3 Client

Tags: windows, 802.1

I just add this .ldf files[Microsoft AD Extenstions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb727029.aspx#) that MS suggest for extending Windows Server 2003 GP to support 802.1x security policy over Wired. both file successfully installed, but I cannot find any changes in Win2k3 GPO. where those policy go?

Is there any suggesstion for implementing this protocol 802.1x in Win2k3 R2 DC and Windows XP SP3 CLient, We want to use wired and computer only policy.